# Runtime exec how to determine when the process terminates without using waitfor()?

Tags: java, android, process, android-asynctask, runtime

I'm running a shell command that requires considerable time to execute, the command runs with no troubles but i can't get the process to abort once started.  I'm using AsyncTask class to run the command to avoid blocking the main thread, here's the code:

```
private class Worker extends AsyncTask <String, Integer, Integer>
{
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground (String... args)
    {
        Process proc = runtime.getRuntime.exec ("some long process...");
        while (/*process still running*/)
        {
            if (isCancellled()) proc.destroy();
        }
        return proc.exitValue();
    }
    .....
}

Worker w = new Worker();
w.execute();
w.cancel (true); // abort
```

How can i find out when the process is finished without blocking the AsyncTask thread? how do i capture the AsyncTask cancelation signal and abort the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a simple solution to abort the runtime process after it starts, i just added a reference to the process in the AsyncTask class and when i need to abort the shell command i would call the `destroy` method on the process and it would terminate:

```
private class Worker extends AsyncTask <String, Integer, Integer>
{
    private Process proc;

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground (String... args)
    {
        try
        {
            this.proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec (command);
            this.proc.waitFor();
            InputStream out = this.proc.getInputStream();
            out.skip (out.available());
            InputStream err = this.proc.getErrorStream();
            err.skip (err.available());
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex)
        {
            Log.i ("runCommand", "Interruped Exception");
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }
        return proc.exitValue();
    }

    public void abort()
    {
        if (this.proc != null) this.proc.destroy();
    }
}

Worker w = new Worker();
w.execute();
w.abort(); // Terminates the process
```